# Sharepoint Online Search is crawling the wrong date/time for pdfs

Tags: sharepoint-online

PDFs uploaded to Office OneDrive and then crawled by Sharepoint Online returns the wrong time modified. It always sets it as a few hours into the future (eg. Tomorrow). All the timezone settings on the site match the ones on my computer so it's correct.

Any ideas what may cause it?